# Ember.js finding current element

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, action

[Here is the pattern](http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/263/)

Inside

```
Songs.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({})
```

we have some events, which are trigerred with `{{action selRow}}` in HTML file.
They do abstract events, but can't define themselves.

In this example I have a table and need to select rows by click and delete selected rows hitting the button, but can't figure out how can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the model object being selected as argument to the selRow event:

```
{{action selRow this}}
```

Now use IndexController to keep track of selected songs. Use route's model hook to start the array empty:

```
Songs.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
      return Ember.A()
  },
});
```

Now the event's make more sense as controller methods:

```
Songs.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  pushMe: function(){
    this.forEach(function(song) {
      console.log('deleting song: ', song.toString());
    });
  },
  selRow: function(song) {
    console.log('I am selected', song, song.toString());
    this.pushObject(song);
  }
});
```

See modified fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HwCx3/

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything works, that's what I was looking for.